# Android Instant App: showInstallPrompt's postInstallIntent does nothing?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-instant-apps

The app in the play store currently is configured to handle `https://www.example.com/hello/`in an intent filter to launch an activity and `showInstallPrompt(...)` is supposed to launch the activity once installation of the app is finished.

https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/reference.html#public_methods

showInstallPrompt(...) Docs:

> Shows a dialog that allows the user to install the current instant app. This method is a no-op if the current running process is an installed app. You must provide a post-install intent, which the system uses to start the application after install is complete.

postInstallIntent Docs:

> The intent to launch after the instant app has been installed. This intent *must* resolve to an activity in the installed app package, or it will not be used.

I've tried doing this:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/hello/");
Intent postInstallIntent = new Intent("action", uri);
InstantApps.showInstallPrompt(MainActivity.this, postInstallIntent, 0, "InstantApp");
```

and this

```
Intent postInstallIntent = new Intent("https://www.example.com/hello/");
InstantApps.showInstallPrompt(MainActivity.this, postInstallIntent, 0, "InstantApp");
```

and this

```
Intent postInstallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/hello/"))
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)
        .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
```

It brings me the the play store, but neither launches the app automatically once the install is completed.

Comment: please have a look on URL https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/faqs.html , if i understand correctly , you have install app in device and then you trying to do this, can check after uninstall apk if installed.

Comment: I had trouble forming the Intent. Thanks to your examples, I found the first one worked to enable showInstallPrompt() for me.

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at:
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/tree/master/install-api
and
https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/blob/master/install-api/features/install/src/main/java/com/instantappsamples/feature/install/InstallApiActivity.kt

- This sample app demonstrates how to use the [Install API](https://developer.android.com/topic/instant-apps/reference.html#showinstallprompt). The API triggers the Intent to install the app on device.
- The call also accepts the Intent, which is triggered after the installation is complete.
- The sample also shows the correct structure to implement `showInstallPrompt` method along with `postInstallIntent`.

Refer the sample code snippet:

```
private val postInstallIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
        Uri.parse("https://install-api.instantappsample.com/")).
        addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE).
        putExtras(Bundle().apply {
            putString("The key to", "sending data via intent")
        })

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_install)

    val isInstantApp = InstantApps.isInstantApp(this)

    findViewById<Button>(R.id.start_installation).apply {
        isEnabled = isInstantApp
        // Show the installation prompt only for an instant app.
        if (isInstantApp) {
            setOnClickListener {
                InstantApps.showInstallPrompt(this@InstallApiActivity,
                        postInstallIntent,
                        REQUEST_CODE,
                        REFERRER)
            } }
    } }
```

Comment: I tried that too, but it still doesn't do anything. I tested the intent filter on my original app multiple times and it is working.

Comment: If it still doesn't work for you then I would suggest you to submit your project to Google's [issuetracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues). They will take a look at it. (also, please share the link to that filed bug here)

Comment: @mco, I hope your error scenario is resolved. Did you check on the above issuetracker link?

Comment: how do handle request when first opening full app? onActivityResult?