# Instant App postInstallIntent crashes because Activity Fails resolution

Tags: android, android-intent, android-instant-apps

I have an `onClickListener()` for a Download button in the sole activity in my Instant App package. When clicked, it forms the `postInstallIntent`:

```
Intent postInstallIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Test.class);
```

When I Run instantapp, it crashes at this line with this **Logcat** entry:

```
    java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/quixr/testqiew2/full/Test;
```

The activity Test is in the feature module *full* and is a Launcher:

```
<application>
    <activity android:name=".Test">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

The `build.gradle` for *app* contains a dependency on *full*:

```
implementation project(':full')
```

Should Test be somewhere else to be found? Or is there a different reason it is not being found?

Comment: Does that activity definition show up in the installed module merged manifest?

Comment: can you check this URL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603099/android-instant-app-showinstallprompts-postinstallintent-does-nothing might it help you

Comment: The Test activity appears in the MergedManifest for app and both of the feature apps, feature and full. It does not appear in the base MergedManifest. The sources for the merge include full, the feature module that includes the Test Activity, only for full and feature - NOT app or base.

Comment: I have seen stackoverflow.com/questions/47603099/. I am trying the various forms of Intent.

Comment: As Pragati mentioned, that intent should be made with a URI, you can see the official example @ https://github.com/googlesamples/android-instant-apps/blob/master/install-api/features/install/src/main/java/com/instantappsamples/feature/install/InstallApiActivity.kt

Comment: Thanks @Pragati-Singh. When I tested the alternatives in /questions/47603099, I found that the URI version worked:     Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://www.example.com/hello/");
Intent postInstallIntent = new Intent("action", uri);  showInstallPrompt returned true while there was a white message box saying "Item not found" which I would expect since the installed module is not yet on the Play Store