# showInstallPrompt not found in InstantApps class

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I'm having this problem.

[image]

I've got these configs..

```
 compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
```

and

```
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.1.1'
    implementation project(':expandablelayout')
    implementation 'com.daimajia.swipelayout:library:1.2.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.timehop.stickyheadersrecyclerview:library:0.4.1@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.26.0'
    implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.5.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
    implementation project(':stripe')
    //implementation files('libs/PayPalAndroidSDK-2.10.1.jar')
    implementation('com.paypal.sdk:paypal-android-sdk:2.16.0') {
        exclude group: 'io.card'
    }
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:4.18.0'
    implementation files('libs/GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4.jar')
    implementation 'me.grantland:autofittextview:0.2.1'
    implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4.8.11@aar'
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.6.3@aar'
```

Ideas ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How come your dependencies is missing:

```
com.google.android.gms:play-services-instantapps
```

Please double check your gradle dependencies elsewhere and make sure it is updated. `16.0.1` works for me.

[/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/InstantApps](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/instantapps/InstantApps)

Comment: Now if you can tell me how the heck I need to use the method... i'd be eternally grateful :D

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48285281/opening-google-play-in-popup-like-vimeo-wisher-buzzfeed-instant-app or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47603099/android-instant-app-showinstallprompts-postinstallintent-does-nothing